# Do software companies intentionally upload fake/infected versions of their own software to file sharing networks as a means to combat piracy?

Tags: p2p

Disclaimer: No illegal activity is condoned in this post. The legality of the described activity varies from country to country.

I remember in the early 00's, when peer to peer file sharing was booming. I would download music from Kazaa. After a few months of happy piracy, I would start getting these music files that were fine for the first 15 seconds, but then started making a horrible buzzing sound for the rest of the track. My 13 year old self speculated that these files may have been intentionally seeded in great numbers by the RIAA or someone like that, in an attempt to flood the network and thus make it useless. They seemed the most likely candidate with means, motive and opportunity to seed so many files on such a large scale. It didn't take long before "verified" file sharing sites started being a popular starting place for p2p.

Recently, on sites like The Pirate Bay, I've seen that there are files that have a huge amount of seeders, but no comments, and they were typically all posted less than a day ago. Typically, the same user has posted many different files like that, and they all have a huge amount of seeders. I have downloaded many such torrents. (Running them in virtual machines for experimental purposes.) Quite often, I have found them to be packed with malware and viruses. (Not just the keygens, which often give false positives, but actual malware that flood your system with advertisements, etc). In other cases it may just be a version of a game that appears to work, but promptly crashes 10% into it, or something like that.

In a normal situation, one would expect the best, cleanest and most functioning version of a program to get the most seeders, as that one would have the best comments under it, and be shared around and accessed the most. Yet that is often not the case. Usually you have to go quite a bit down the list to actually find a good torrent with good comments.

Who are regularly reuploading these bad/infected versions of software, and seeding them on a large scale? Who has the means, motive and opportunity to do this?

One thing that comes to mind is botnets who just want to distribute adware, and thus make money. That's quite possible. But that doesn't explain versions of software that simply don't work, or appear to work at first, but malfunction after a short time (no adware).

If I was Adobe, or Rockstar Games, or Microsoft or someone like that, I would recognize what an incredible blow online piracy is to my company's revenue. These companies' income would increase immensely if online piracy disappeared or was greatly reduced. And actually, trying to find pirated versions of software and instead getting all these fakes and malware on top of the list, is a great deterrent that probably stops lots of people from pirating, leading many of them to buy the software instead.

If I was these companies, I would find uploading and seeding this stuff on a large scale quite a good idea, in an attempt to combat piracy of the software I sell.

But, would it be illegal of them to do so? Sure, they are only punishing people who are already breaking the law. (Unless someone was in a country that hasn't banned piracy), but would it still be illegal for a company to distribute viruses in that way? I mean, the viruses may spread further, infecting innocent people's computers.

Is there any evidence that software companies actually engage in this form of piracy prevention? You may include instances where a company has paid a proxy entity to engage in the activity for them.

Comment: This is a very broad question and most of this (including the legal aspects) is off-topic here. Please [read what is on-topic](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and restrict your question to this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Are you sure about the off topic part? What about this question? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20806/are-anti-virus-companies-companies-regularly-committing-software-piracy

Comment: I find the question you referenced  off-topic too because it exclusively deals with legals aspects.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Alright. If one or two more people agree I will edit out the legal aspects of the question.

Comment: It would make a big difference if the fake software was just non-functional, or actively damaged the user's computer. The latter would certainly be illegal in the UK, and I expect most countries.

Comment: @paj28 Yeah, makes sense.

Comment: @paj28 Note that non-functional fake software which causes system crashes might be considered illegal, as well.

Comment: I went regularly to a cinema in my town, where they were showing a "sneak", you go in and dont know which movie it will be. Sometimes you were lucky and a blockbuster was shown weeks or even months before being released. After a while, some of the audio of the blockbusters appeared on internet sites. I learned, that the audio has certain cracks and noise that were generated by the movie company in order to track, which movie was sent to which cinema. After several attempts to catch the pirates failed, the sneak lost their blockbusters and was finally stopped. :(

Comment: @hamena314 So the audio was recorded by guests with tape recorders, right? Was the cinema blamed for not being able to catch them?

Comment: Tape recorders or something similar, they never got caught but boasted in the discussion forum of the cinema about it. There are devices that look like a pen and record audio, almost impossible to find. The cinema even called the cops 2-3 times, so some audience members had to go outside, be searched and then left back in. Others noticed this and raged, since the police searched random movie goers. I dont know if the cinema was blamed, but I dont know how they should have catched the pirates. Collect all smartphones beforehand? All pens, all glasses (embedded recorder?), all bags,...

Comment: @hamena314 It's almost impossible to enforce. When people film screeners, at least you have a chance of catching them because the lense has to be visible somehow. But even then it's difficult, because the lens can be very small and hidden in something.

Answer (score 5):

I would suspect that intentionally causing harm to other peoples' computers is illegal in most parts of the world. I also believe that in most parts of the world someone committing a crime against you (or in this case just having *the intention* to do so) does not necessarily give you the right to commit a crime against them. But as with most people on this website, my area of expertise is technology, not law. So I would refer you to the people on [law stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) which might explain this far better than we could.

No, these malware-infested pirated copies are usually spread by criminals who have no affiliation with the game companies and are looking for an easy way to grow their botnets.

Regarding low-quality versions which malfunction after a while: There is a huge competition between piracy groups to be the first to release a certain game. That means they often do not take time to test the game properly to make sure that *all* copy protection features are disabled properly and without breaking anything. Also, games are sometimes leaked and pirated before the actual release (a common source are press pre-release copies), so various last-minute patches and bugfixes might not be applied yet which do exist in the actual release version.

But I know of [one case where a company openly admitted to uploading a modified version of their game to piracy websites](http://www.greenheartgames.com/2013/04/29/what-happens-when-pirates-play-a-game-development-simulator-and-then-go-bankrupt-because-of-piracy/). However, their modifications were not malicious. They just made the game unplayable in a quite original way:

> When we released our very first game, Game Dev Tycoon (for Mac, Windows and Linux) yesterday, we did something unusual and as far as I know unique. We released a cracked version of the game ourselves, minutes after opening our Store. [...]
>   The cracked version is nearly identical to the real thing except for one detail… [...] as players spend a few hours playing and growing their own game dev company, they will start to see the following message, styled like any other in-game message
>
> > **Boss, it seems that while many players play our new game, they steal it by downloading a cracked version rather than buying it legally.
> >     If players don’t buy the games they like, we will sooner or later go bankrupt.**
>
> Slowly their in-game funds dwindle, and new games they create have a high chance to be pirated until their virtual game development company goes bankrupt.

And then they amused themselves about the software pirates who posted on the official support forum complaining that the software piracy game mechanic is completely overpowered and that there should be a way to take legal actions against the software pirates or develop DRM technology to stop them.

Comment: Haha, the story about Game Dev Tycoon is very funny. Especially the users coming to the official forums and complaining. Skilled trolling.

Comment: By the developers, I mean.

Comment: I am speculating, but some users test a game / program and later buy it, sometimes even years later. If they test it and it does not work, they might later not buy it and even think that the company that made the game / program does not develop good products. Would be interesting to find out if these methods have an impact or not.

Comment: +1 for the Game Dev Tycoon anecdote.